# Is the new Primefaces showcase theme downloadable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, themes

the [Primefaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/) has a new theme. It looks very cool and modern (in contrast to the old Aristo one).

If I look in the source, I cannot find a proper theme name (or it's a highly customized Aristo theme).

I've [asked the question in the PF forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=38080), without any response, so, Stackoverflow is my last hope to find an answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the following answer of the PF lead:

> It is not a theme, just the design of showcase. But we plan to create
>   a theme based on it in future just like we created home theme from
>   primefaces.org

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the showcase theme is obtainable from any of the other custom themes. They implemented their own theme into making the showcase.

Comment: That's a great pity. :(